# androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar not showing title

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-toolbar

The toolbar shows when I add it to the layout of `activity_main` but `setSupportActionbar()` in `MainActivity` doesn't seem to make a difference in the appearance at least.

What I really don't understand is why the app title isn't showing.  I've tried adding it in the layout and programmatically in `MainActivity`

I'm not sure if my issue is with the themes or with the version of `ToolBar` I am using

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:barrierAllowsGoneWidgets="false"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:title="@string/app_name"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/black" />



    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(),NewSongFragment.NewSongListener {

    private val songViewModel: SongViewModel by viewModels {
        SongViewModelFactory((application as SongApplication).repository)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        //setup toolbar
        setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar))
        supportActionBar?.title = "My title"

        //create view
        val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycler_view)
        val adapter = ItemAdapter(this,
            ItemAdapter.OnClickListener { rating -> songViewModel.insertRating(rating) }
        )
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

        //initialize data
        songViewModel.allSongs.observe(this) { song ->
            // Update the cached copy of the songs in the adapter.
            song.let { adapter.submitList(it) }
        }


        // Use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
        // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)

        //add song button
        val fab = findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.fab)
        fab.setOnClickListener {
            showNewSongDialog()
            }
        }

    private fun showNewSongDialog() {
        // Create an instance of the dialog fragment and show it
        val dialog = NewSongFragment()
        dialog.show(supportFragmentManager, "NewSongFragment")
    }
    override fun onDialogPositiveClick(newSongTitle: String, newSongBPM: Int) {
        // User touched the dialog's positive button

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(newSongTitle)){

        }else{
            val newSong = Song(newSongTitle,newSongBPM)
            songViewModel.insertSong(newSong)
            val rating = Rating(System.currentTimeMillis(),newSong.songTitle, 50)
            songViewModel.insertRating(rating)
        }

    }

    override fun onDialogNegativeClick(dialog: DialogFragment) {
        // User touched the dialog's negative button
    }


}
```

themes.xml

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.Songs" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/fuchsia_001</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/blue_500</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.songs">

    <application
        android:name=".SongApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Songs">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Let me know if I need to break out my gradle files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems okay, but in your XML layout file, you are hiding your toolbar with fragment. Change your code as follow:

> activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".MainActivity">
  
 <!-- remove this line android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"-->
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:barrierAllowsGoneWidgets="false"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:title="@string/app_name"
    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
    app:titleTextColor="@color/black" />



<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/my_toolbar"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />


 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: no luck.  I was already able to see the toolbar just fine.  It's the title that isn't showing.

Comment: did you try my code? because in your code you are hiding the title with the fragment. I know it shows the toolbar but this line (android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize) was causing your title to hide.

Comment: and try to change your text color.

Comment: my bad.  I made the comment and somehow forgot to delete the padding.  The title is showing now!  xml comments are a pain....  I wonder why I had that padding in there in the first place.

Comment: can you upvote this too?  It would be helpful.

Comment: Hey @RudraRokaya can you please help me on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72685383/11560810)